# If we had children wear an apparatus swapping e.g. Red and Blue colors, would their perception adapt?

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience, neuroanatomy, visual-system

In the context of neuroscience and philosophy, one difficult question is what makes colors so peculiar and vivid if they're just signals encoding light intensity coming from certain receptors -- an instance of the "Problem of Qualia". In other words, why do perceived colors take their particular "qualitative" appearance. Experiments like color matching functions and simple mathematical properties clearly cannot fully account for this qualitative appearance -- a mathematical model like the opponent process:

[image: Opponent process model]

can explain for instance that yellow and blue or red and green should appear to be in opposition, but it cannot explain exactly why we perceive *green* to be our particular *green* and not some other qualitatively distinct perception with the same mathematical properties.

> 1) Are the "appearances" of red, green and blue the only possible
>   "appearances" that satisfy the mathematical properties of colors in
>   our visual system? Or more generally are those simple mathematical
>   properties plus their general relation to objects in nature sufficient
>   to explain their subjective appearance? (say we had a propensity to
>   like and perceive blue positively because of it's association with
>   clear whether)

I suspect not. Intuitively I suspect there are a number of different ways colors could qualitatively appear like that go beyond this simple mathematical model and their association with seen objects, embedded in the structure of our brain's complex neural networks. But I don't have a convincing argument to support this conclusion.

I wonder what kinds of experiments can be done to explore this subject, and what experiments have already been done.

One such (imaginary) experiment that comes to mind is swapping different colors a child sees since birth with an ocular device. If the statistical association of objects and color signals were decisive for qualitative color perception, we might expect that then color preference (the favorite which is usually blue) would shift accordingly if we swapped red and blue -- people should start preferring Red over Blue.

> 2) Do we have any evidence suggesting the outcome of this kind of experiment (and the nature of perception in general)?

Comment: Your first question needs re-phrasing. Can you define "appearances" and "mathematical properties of colors in our visual system" more clearly? You insinuate that "appearances" are associated with preference, but surely that's not all there is to it, is it? The experiment you are suggesting sounds a lot like [Mary the neuroscientist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_argument).

Comment: @vkehayas I'll think about it. Indeed my experiment is in the same vein of Mary the neuroscientist, but it has a big difference. I'm not questioning that physical processing gives rise to experiences with a phenomenal character (I'm assuming it -- I dismiss 'Mary the nsc.' since Mary). I'm questioning mostly why our phenomenal qualities are thus-and-so. Is the particular character of our experiences explainable solely by the visual system and what we see, or do we have to dive further into the brain for a complete explanation?

Comment: @vkehayas Also I associate "appearance" with preference, but I mostly mean that "appearance" should (weakly) imply preference: that Blue appears the particular way it appears to us would imply that most people like the color Blue the most -- which is empirically true; and not that preference fully describes "appearance". If preference changes when swapping colors (subjects prefer Red over Blue), that would be evidence that the appearance of colors is a function of the statistics of what we see -- that perhaps the "appearance" or "look" of nature has remained unchanged even with the swap.

Comment: But if preference remains the same, then it seems safe to conclude the appearance of isolated colors is independent of the statistics of our observations. That we don't like and perceive Blue in a particular way just because the sky is blue, or that we don't have a particular sensation associated with green just because trees and leaves are green.

Comment: "*...or do we have to dive further into the brain for a complete explanation?*": I think that this sentence, and the spirit behind it, is useful to include in the question. Your comments make what you are asking much clearer to me, so please consider editing the question to reflect those. I am unclear on the data concerning the preference to blue and would like to see a reference if you can provide it. Regarding the statistics of the environment and the preference to blue color:https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/24481